# Using Automapper with generics

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a base class Repository which contains base functionality for a set of classes that inherit from it such as UserRepository or DepartmentRepository.

I'm using automapper to map between my entity framework objects and my domain objects.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class {
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context) {
        Context = context;
    }

    public TEntity Get(int id) {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }
}

public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository {
    public UserRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {
    }

    public User GetUserByNTId(string NTId) {
        return Mapper.Map<User>(DbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.NTId == NTId));
    }

}
```

`GetUserByNTId` will work because I can use automapper in the return statement. But `Get` will not work because it deals with `TEntity` and I don't know how you can tell automapper to examine the type of `TEntity` and look for a matching mapping.

How can I change the return statement of the Get function so that it will work for all my derived repositories and still use automapper? Or do I just have to take all my general functions and push them down into the derived classes and eliminate the Repository base class?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad idea to for mixing AutoMapper and other responsibilities when querying from a **Repository pattern**. It's also of course a violation of the **Single Responsibility Principle**.

A naive non tested implementation will be:

```
public class ExampleOfGenericRepository<TEntity> : Repository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public ExampleOfGenericRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TEntity>(Get(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. If using the generic Get function with the UserRepository you get the error "The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context." Something about the combination of generics, automapper and entity framework that doesn't play nice. The Get function works fine if I put it directly in UserRepository and specify concrete mappings.